# How can I build a buying options feature similar to myfonts.com using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, product

I'm looking for assistance on building a feature similar to the buying options on the website https://www.myfonts.com/products/thin-twogether-rounded-608233/licenses. I'm developing my website using WordPress.

I would appreciate guidance on understanding the structure and key considerations involved in building this feature from scratch.

my products
product  post type = post
product post type = magazine

I need guidance on improving my approach and understanding the required structure for implementing this in WordPress.